# ActionBar didn't work?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

My application crashes and I get

**Error :**

> setNavigationMode(int)' on a null object reference

**Code :**

```
package com.example.muhammad_adel.tabs;


import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ActionBar actionBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("one"));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("two"));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("three"));
    }
}
```

Comment: change getActionBar() to getSupportActionBar(); and check it.

Comment: Die you create a menu to respond to?

Comment: @RujulGandhi the same problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30625128/java-lang-nullpointerexception-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-actionbar-setn

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya it's Already parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I find the solution** thanks for your help

First instead of import android.app.ActionBar => **import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar**

Second changing this actionBar = getActionBar(); to **actionbar = getSupportActionBar();**

Third you must implement **TabListener**

Answer (score 2):

**Change 1 :** instead of `import android.support.v4.app.ActionBar` use `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` in your activity

**Change 2 :** change this `actionBar = getActionBar();` to `actionbar = getSupportActionBar();`

**Update:**

You have to use `PagerSlidingTabStrip` because `setNavigationMode` is now `deprecated`.

Comment: i get this exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Action Bar Tab must have a Callback

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726759/actionbar-setnavigationmodeactionbar-navigation-mode-tabs-deprecated

Answer (score 1):

It's been long time since **`ActionBar` got deprecated**.

Try to use `Toolbar` and `SlidingTabs`.

Please refer to this answer for same question. It will provide you enough guide for your query.

[Android, Tabs without Actionbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23843479/android-tabs-without-actionbar/23843814#23843814)

You can easily implement this and it will be easy for you to handle `onClick()` events for tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You should Try to change your parent style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```